# is there anyway pure JS can send emails or any other notifications to other devices?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

So, I am a student, looking for accommodations, I am writing a script to notify me when there are new rooms. here is what I have so far.

```
roomNumber = $('div .object-list-items-container').children('section').length;


function ifNewRoom() {
    newRoomNumber = $('div .object-list-items- 
   container').children('section').length;
    console.log('the last room number is' + roomNumber);
    console.log('the lastest room number is' + newRoomNumber + '\n');    
    var d = new Date();
    if (newRoomNumber !== roomNumber) {
        roomNumber = newRoomNumber;
        console.log('new room on ' + d );
    } else {
        console.log('nothing on ' + d);
    }

    var t = setTimeout('ifNewRoom()', 1000*60*5);

/* debug
    console.log(roomNumber);
    console.log(newRoomNumber); */

}
```

I have tested it, it works well in chrome console since there aren't many items so All I care is the number change, now I just need to figure out this will notify me via email or anything onto my phone since I will leave this code run on PC at home while I leave for work.

I don't know node.js or express

Any ideas may help me out?

Comment: There's no way to send an email directly from client-side JS alone. You would need to use JS to make a request to another server-side location which does have this ability. Alternatively you could use a third-party such as SendGrid, however they will charge you for the service.

Comment: That would be extremely dangerous to let client side javascript send mails. You need to do it at the backend, using PHP, NodeJS, Python, etc...

Comment: I think one of possible solution for you is to use web push notification.